# How to make a chatbot using python which can understand my question and then answer it

Tags: python, machine-learning, logic, artificial-intelligence, chatbot

I want to know that if I make a chatbot using python and in the code I says that if I say How are you?then it should say I am good but I want him to understand my question like if I say him What's up then he should understand that it means how are you and then answer my question of this.

I tried to make a chatbot who can understand my questions but when I made it it can only answer the questions which I wrote in the code.I am expecting that the chatbot should answer the question after understanding what it means.

Comment: Do you want to build a chatbot engine that can respond based on chat history? Do you also use OpenAI ChatGPT?

Comment: No i dont have access of openai Api.and no I dont want him to respond based on chat history.Suppose I coded my chat that if someone give him input How are you?Then the output should come that I am good.But I want him to also answer if anyone say what's up by relating it with how are you question